# Eclipse: ABAP communication layer is not configured... no sapjco3 in java.library.path

Tags: abap, eclipse-luna, java.library.path, sapjco3

**Situation:**

After downloading and installing Eclipse Luna. 
Then Installing SAP Plugins: HANA, ABAP

**Issue:**

Error Message pops up when Eclipse starts:

ABAP communication layer is not configured properly. This might be caused by missing Microsoft Runtime DLLs VS2010. Consult the installation guide or download page for further details on how to install this component.

JCo initialization failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no `sapjco3` in `java.libray.path`

[image: Eclipse Error Message]

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

Use Eclipse Mars since the error did not occur there.

**Solution 2:**

**1. locate or get the `sapjco3` file:**

Use an appropriate search tool to check if sapjco3 file exists on your computer: I use unix-tools on windows and search for sapjo3 like this:

```
$ find /c -iname '*sapjco3*' 2> find-sapjco3.err.txt
```

Be aware that you need the unix-tool find for that command.
 *Be also aware that the windows search function may not find the file.*

I found the file und this path:

```
C:/\Users\thorsten.niehues\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.5.0_1884348784_win32_win32_x86_64\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1060\0\.cp\lib\sapjco3.dll
```

In case the file is not located on your computer then you need the get it from the internet e.g. SAP Market Place (you need an S-User for the Marketplace)

**2. Place the file in a path listed by java.library.path:**

The paths can be determined by: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

Answer (score 1):

If you are in windows, just install the update of Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package

https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/update-for-visual-c-2013-redistributable-package-d8ccd6a5-4e26-c290-517b-8da6cfdf4f10

Comment: Thank you very much, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know I also had a problem like this recently. I had researched so many answers but what I did is just installed the latest kepler eclipse and everything worked fine.